# How to use os.walk and use intersection files in two folders and sub subfolders (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two folders all the files , files with same file name , and many files in subfolders , and print full path

```
def aaa(self):

  dira = self.lineA.text()
  dirb = self.lineB.text()
  dirafile = [os.path.join(path, dirafile) for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dira) for dirafile in files]
  dirbfile = [os.path.join(path, dirbfile) for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dirb) for dirbfile in files]
  dirfileok = set(dirbfile).intersection(dirafile)
  print(dirfileok)
```

but print results "set()" , Why ???

Comment: What do `dirafile` and `dirbfile` look like?

Comment: dirafile is folderA , dirbfile is folderB . 

e.g. 
folderA:
D:\python\PycharmProjects\folderA\01.txt
D:\python\PycharmProjects\folderA\02.txt 
D:\python\PycharmProjects\folderA\AAA\04.txt 

folderB:
D:\python\PycharmProjects\folderB\02.txt
D:\python\PycharmProjects\folderB\03.txt
D:\python\PycharmProjects\folderB\AAA\04.txt

Comment: If that's what's actually in them, then you're getting `set()` because there's no intersection between those lists. The `dirafile` items have `folderA` in them where the `dirbfile` items have `folderB`.